# i have dell 5583 i7 which ssd i choose?

Tags: ssd

I have laptop dell 5583 i7 and I want to get m.2 for it and I use it for flutter android studio

which one I choose

> kingstone m.2 a400 240gb 500/500 read/write
>
> adata xpg m.2 s11 nvme 240gb 3000/1500 read/write

will I benefit from the highest write/read rate on my laptop?

Comment: It would be nice to see the prices or price difference for these two SSDs. The ADATA XPG m.2. is faster on paper, but not necessarily better *value* than the Kingston SSD, possibly not even providing more speed *per dollar*. I wouldn't be concerned with the read/write speeds as much as the brand, warranty, and life expectancy of the drive.

Answer (score 1):

Those SSDs are NOT comparable.

The first option,

> Kingston SSD A400 m.2 240GB

is an mSATA m.2 SSD, the latter

> ADATA XPG GAMMIX S11

is an NVMe m.2 SSD - using PCIe instead of SATA for the connection.

According to its manual [found here](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/inspiron-15-5583-laptop_users-guide_en-us.pdf), your laptop supports NVMe SSDs.

Answer (score 0):

**Go for Adata XPG M.2 S11 NVMe 240GB**

```
This SSD is not only faster also better life which may serve you for long time.
```